# How can I map the Express Keys on a Wacom Intuos Pro L Touch to enable or disable the touch functionality?

Tags: gnome, 16.04, ubuntu-gnome, wacom

Any idea if it's possible to properly map the Express Keys on a Wacom Intuos Pro L tablet like you can with the Windows drivers?
It doesn't seem to be working for me on Ubuntu GNOME and I really need to be able to switch Touch on and off via the Express Keys.

Most posts I've found about Wacom tablet keys are rather cryptic, so if anyone could give me or point me to an idiot-proof step-by-step explanation, I'd appreciate it greatly!

I'm on Ubuntu GNOME 16.04